# Spring Validator validate method never called

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, jsp

I have two close to each other controllers - one for products and one for users.
I'd like to add Spring Validation to both controllers.
So I added ProductValidator and UserValidator classes which implement Validator.
ProductValidator works fine.
The problem is UserValidator is never called.
InitBinder method is being called, but validation doesn't work.
At the same time everything works fine with products in ProductController.

Here's the code of user logic.

UserController

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(path = "/users")
public class UserController {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final RoleService roleService;
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService, RoleService roleService, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.roleService = roleService;
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userValidator")
    private UserValidator userValidator;

    @InitBinder("user")
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(userValidator);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(Role.class, "roles", new RoleEditor(roleService));
    }

    ...

    @RequestMapping(path = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView submit(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid User user,
                         BindingResult result) {
        ...
    }
...
}
```

UserValidator

```
@Component("userValidator")
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserValidator(UserRepository userRepository, RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> paramClass) {
        return User.class.equals(paramClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {

        User user = (User) obj;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "username", "username.required", "Enter username");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "firstName.required", "Enter user first name");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", "lastName.required", "Enter user last name");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "password", "password.required", "Enter user password");

        User userToFind = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()).orElse(new User());

        if (Objects.isNull(user.getId()) && Objects.nonNull(userToFind.getId())) {
            errors.rejectValue("username", "username.already.exist", "user with this username already exists");
        }

        if (Objects.isNull(user.getRoles())) {
            errors.rejectValue("roles", "role.required", "role must be assigned");

        }

        Role adminRole = roleRepository.getAdminRole();
        if (Objects.nonNull(user.getId())
                && Objects.nonNull(user.getRoles())
                && !user.getRoles().contains(adminRole)
                && userRepository.findUsersWithAdministratorRole().size() == 1) {
            errors.rejectValue("roles", "admin.required", "at least one admin role must exist");
        }
    }

    public ErrorMessage validateUserToDelete(UUID id) {
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage();
        List<String> errors = new ArrayList<>();
        Set<User> admins = userRepository.findUsersWithAdministratorRole();

        if (admins.size() == 1) {
            errors.add(String.format("User with email %s is the one with Admin role. Impossible to delete last Admin user."
                    , userRepository.findById(id).get().getUsername()));
        }
        errorMessage.setErrors(errors);
        return errorMessage;
    }
}
```

User

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    private UUID id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private BigDecimal money;
    private Set<Role> roles;
    private Set<Product> products;

    @Id
    @Type(type="org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "username")
    @NotEmpty
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Column(name = "password")
    @NotEmpty
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @NotEmpty
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Column(name = "money")
    @DecimalMin(value = "0.0", inclusive = false)
    @Digits(integer = 10, fraction = 2)
    public BigDecimal getMoney() {
        return money;
    }
    public void setMoney(BigDecimal money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "role_id") }
    )
    @NotNull
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "checkout",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }
    )
    public Set<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(Set<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return id.equals(user.id) && username.equals(user.username) && password.equals(user.password) && firstName.equals(user.firstName) && lastName.equals(user.lastName);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, username, password, firstName, lastName);
    }
}
```

user.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <c:import url="${contextPath}/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp"/>
    </head>

    <body>

        <c:import url="${contextPath}/WEB-INF/jsp/navibar.jsp"/>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                    <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                        <a href="/users" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Back to users</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </security:authorize>
            </div><br>
        <form:form action="/users/save" method="post" modelAttribute="user">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <form:label path="id">User ID:</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="id" type="UUID" readonly="true" class="form-control" id="id" placeholder="User ID" name="id" value="${user.id}"/>
                    <br>
                    <form:label path="username">username (email address):</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username" name="username" value="${user.username}"/>
                    <form:errors path="username" cssClass="error"/>
                    <br>
                    <form:label path="password">Password:</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="password" type="text" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password" value="${user.password}"/>
                    <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error"/>
                    <br>
                    <form:label path="firstName">First name:</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="Enter first name" name="firstName" value="${user.firstName}"/>
                    <form:errors path="firstName" cssClass="error"/>
                    <br>
                    <form:label path="lastName">First name:</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="lastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="Enter last name" name="lastName" value="${user.lastName}"/>
                    <form:errors path="lastName" cssClass="error"/>
                    <br>
                    <form:label path="money">Money:</form:label><br>
                    <form:input path="money" type="number" class="form-control" id="money" placeholder="Enter money" name="money" value="${user.money}"/>
                    <form:errors path="money" cssClass="error"/>
                    <br>
                    <security:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                    <form:label path="roles">Roles:</form:label><br>
                    <c:forEach items="${roles}" var="role">
                        <form:checkbox path="roles" id="${roles}" label="${role.name}" value="${role}"/></td>
                    </c:forEach>
                    <br>
                    <form:errors path="roles" cssClass="error"/><br><br>
                    </security:authorize>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
                        <div class="btn-group me-2" role="group" aria-label="Second group">
                            <form:button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</form:button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `User.class.isAssignableFrom(paramClass)`. The `equals` might fail if a proxy of sorts (or a subclass for whatever reason) is involved.

Comment: I've just tried with no luck.
As I see now, supports method is not called too.

Comment: Then there must be something you aren't showing that breaks things. You are also injecting the validator twice (once as `validatorService` and once as `userValidator` so which is it?). I would also make the `initBinder` annotated method `public` instead of `private`. Finally which `@Valid` annotation are you using? Have you tried, `@Validated` from Spring?

Comment: I have this trying to debug it 
Method threw 'org.springframework.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.intellias.testmarketplace.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$309171b7.toString()

Comment: I have some other methods in 'UserValidator' class and use them.
I have exactly the same logic in 'ProductController' and it works fine.
I tried to use '@Validated'. It skips initBinder call that way.

Comment: Why is there a proxy created for this controller? still don't inject it twice just reuse the `UserValidator`.

Comment: The logic (if injecting things twice) is wrong, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: I've edited `UserController` code. No luck. Problem is the same.
Validator becomes `null` during it's setup.

Comment: I still suspect the `private` method is the problem as a proxy is being generated but that doesn't work for `private` methods, thus not seeing a validator being injected. But the question is **why** is this proxy even being generated? Nonetheless the method should be `public`.

Comment: @M.Deinum
That's crazy but it helped. Thank you.
The strange thing is ProductController works with `private` initBinder

Comment: If you check the class name from your debugger `com.intellias.testmarketplace.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$309171b7.` the `$$EnhancerBySpring` part indicates this is a proxy (so there must be something on your controller that you didn't include in the question) that leads to a proxy being created (like an `@PreAuthorize` annotation). A proxy will only work for `public` or `protected` methods as a class based proxy is created (extending the original one). The proxy doesn't have anything injected it passes calls to the delegate (unless a `final` or `private` method is called

Comment: Some `UserController` methods have `@PreAuthorize` annotation. You are right.
Adding it to any `ProductController` methods fails `ProductValidator`setup too.
Can you share where I can read more about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the classname from your debugger `com.intellias.testmarketplace.controller.UserController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$309171b7` you see the `$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB`. That part indicates that a proxy is being generated by Spring. A proxy can be generated for various reasons but the most common one for controllers is security, the `@PreAuthorize` annotation comes to mind. Another option is the `@Timed` annotation to do monitoring on the controller.

As your `initBinder` method is `private` this will be invoked directly on the proxy and **not** on the actual bean instance. This is due to a class proxy being created, which works by extending your class. A method is being generated with the same signature and the interceptor is invoked and then the call is passed on to the actual method. However this will only work for `public` and `protected` methods **not** for `private` or `final` methods. Those will be directly invoked on the empty proxy (the fields are `null` as that doesn't need the dependencies).

As your method is `private` it is invoked on the proxy. The proxy doesn't have the fields set, so the `userValidator` is `null`. So effectivly there is no `Validator` being set on the `WebDataBinder` and thus no validation will and can be done.

To fix, make the method `public` (or `protected`) so that it will properly be called on the actual bean and not the proxy.

For the future and as a rule of thumb you probably want your methods with annotations in a controller to be `public` anyway instead of `private.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in private access modifier for `initBinder` method combined with `@PreAuthorize` annotation on some `UserController` methods.
Many thanks to @M.Deinum for patience and help.